# How to connect to a wireless AP which has no SSID?

Tags: wifi

Today while scaning APs from a PCI adapter I saw an AP which had no name(SSID), and when I tried to connect to this AP the option of connect button is disabled and I was unable to connect to the AP. If you know how to connect to such AP, then kindly tell me please. [SEE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9E1c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AP is in a stealth mode, meaning it doesn't broadcast the SSID (i.e., the network "name"). In order to connect to such network you need to know the SSID in advance and configure it in properties. This is a simple security feature used to prevent unauthorized connection.